# Lyx custom layout for command: newline should stay in same environment?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I am writing a Lyx custom `.layout`, specifically for a class-specific TeX command that takes the form `\command{}`. I want that when typing a newline in Lyx, the new lines stays within the `\command{}`, emulating what happens when you enter a newline in the Lyx standard abstract environment. However, so far this is not the case, a new line will  create a new separate `\command{}\command{}`.

Which layout parameters do I need to have so that newline stay within the same environment? I tried various combinations of `ParbreakIsNewline`, `ParagraphGroup`, `Newline` but to no avail so far.

*Note*: this works out correctly if I use instead `LatexType  Environment`, so maybe an alternative solution could be to just write an environment that wraps the `\command{}`? Seems basic, but not sure how to do it unfortunately.

The code (full code on [github](https://github.com/MatthieuStigler/ucdavisthesislyx/blob/master/ucdavisthesis.layout)):

```
Style Acknowledgments2
  CopyStyle  OfficialMajor
  #LatexType  Environment
  ParagraphGroup 1
  Margin     First_Dynamic
  NextNoIndent          0
  LatexName  acknowledgments
  InTitle    1
  Newline    0
  LabelString Acknowledgments
  LabelType  Static
  LabelSep  ":  "
  LabelFont
    Color    brown
    Series   Bold
  EndFont
End
```